# SQL IO and SAN troubles

Tags: sqlio

We are running two servers with identical software setup but different hardware.

The first one is a VM on VMWare on a normal tower server with dual core xeons, 16 GB RAM and a 7200 RPM drive.

The second one is a VM on XenServer on a powerful brand new rack server, with 4 core xeons and shared storage.

We are running Dynamics AX 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2. When I insert 15 000 records into a table on the slow tower server (as a test), it does so in 13 seconds. On the fast server it takes 33 seconds. I re-ran these tests several times with the same results.

I have a feeling it is some sort of IO bottleneck, so I ran SQLIO on both.

Here are the results for the slow tower server:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>test.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -o8 -frandom -b8 -BH -LS C:\Tes
tFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 14318180 counts per second
8 threads writing for 120 secs to file C:\TestFile.dat
        using 8KB random IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: C:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:   226.97
MBs/sec:     1.77
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 0
Avg_Latency(ms): 281
Max_Latency(ms): 467
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 99

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -o8 -frandom -b8 -BH -LS C:\Tes
tFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 14318180 counts per second
8 threads reading for 120 secs from file C:\TestFile.dat
        using 8KB random IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: C:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:    91.34
MBs/sec:     0.71
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 14
Avg_Latency(ms): 699
Max_Latency(ms): 1124
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 100

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS C
:\TestFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 14318180 counts per second
8 threads writing for 120 secs to file C:\TestFile.dat
        using 64KB sequential IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: C:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:  1094.50
MBs/sec:    68.40
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 0
Avg_Latency(ms): 58
Max_Latency(ms): 467
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 100

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS C
:\TestFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 14318180 counts per second
8 threads reading for 120 secs from file C:\TestFile.dat
        using 64KB sequential IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: C:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:  1155.31
MBs/sec:    72.20
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 17
Avg_Latency(ms): 55
Max_Latency(ms): 205
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 100
```

Here are the results of the fast rack server:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>test.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -o8 -frandom -b8 -BH -LS E:\Tes
tFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads writing for 120 secs to file E:\TestFile.dat
        using 8KB random IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
open_file: CreateFile (E:\TestFile.dat for write): The system cannot find the pa
th specified.
exiting

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -o8 -frandom -b8 -BH -LS E:\Tes
tFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads reading for 120 secs from file E:\TestFile.dat
        using 8KB random IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
open_file: CreateFile (E:\TestFile.dat for read): The system cannot find the pat
h specified.
exiting

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS E
:\TestFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads writing for 120 secs to file E:\TestFile.dat
        using 64KB sequential IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
open_file: CreateFile (E:\TestFile.dat for write): The system cannot find the pa
th specified.
exiting

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS E
:\TestFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads reading for 120 secs from file E:\TestFile.dat
        using 64KB sequential IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
open_file: CreateFile (E:\TestFile.dat for read): The system cannot find the pat
h specified.
exiting

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>test.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -o8 -frandom -b8 -BH -LS c:\Tes
tFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads writing for 120 secs to file c:\TestFile.dat
        using 8KB random IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: c:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:  2575.77
MBs/sec:    20.12
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 1
Avg_Latency(ms): 24
Max_Latency(ms): 655
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  5  8  9  9  9  8  5  3  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 37

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -o8 -frandom -b8 -BH -LS c:\Tes
tFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads reading for 120 secs from file c:\TestFile.dat
        using 8KB random IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: c:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:  1141.39
MBs/sec:     8.91
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 1
Avg_Latency(ms): 55
Max_Latency(ms): 652
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 91

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS c
:\TestFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads writing for 120 secs to file c:\TestFile.dat
        using 64KB sequential IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: c:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:   341.37
MBs/sec:    21.33
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 5
Avg_Latency(ms): 186
Max_Latency(ms): 120037
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 100

C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO>sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS c
:\TestFile.dat
sqlio v1.5.SG
using system counter for latency timings, 62500000 counts per second
8 threads reading for 120 secs from file c:\TestFile.dat
        using 64KB sequential IOs
        enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
        buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
using current size: 5120 MB for file: c:\TestFile.dat
initialization done
CUMULATIVE DATA:
throughput metrics:
IOs/sec:  1024.07
MBs/sec:    64.00
latency metrics:
Min_Latency(ms): 5
Avg_Latency(ms): 61
Max_Latency(ms): 81632
histogram:
ms: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24+
%:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 100
```

Three of the four tests are, to my mind, within reasonable parameters for the rack server. However, the 64 write test is *incredibly* slow on the rack server. (68 mb/sec on the slow tower vs 21 mb/s on the rack). The read speed for 64k also seems slow.

Is this enough to say there is some sort of bottleneck with the shared storage? I need to know if I can take this evidence and say we need to launch an investigation into this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed your "urgent help" from the topic of the question. If you need urgent help then call a SQL consultant.

Answer (score 0):

Please test your xenserver performance with Citrix Performance VM: [Link](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX127065)

It will run as a VM and test disk & network IO